# How to initialize Parse pointer in my subclass

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I know how to set up strings and such, but how to set up a pointer to another class? Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class Tag: PFObject {

   override class func initialize() {
      struct Static {
         static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
      }
      dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {

         self.registerSubclass()
      }
   }

   @NSManaged var ID: String?
   @NSManaged var stanceName: String?
   @NSManaged var stanceValue: NSNumber?

   // HOW DO I DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS?
   @NSManaged var user: PointerToUserClass?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user class is special, do it this way:

```
@NSManaged var user: PFUser?
```

For other Parse objects, use:

```
@NSManaged var object: PFObject?
```

Or, if you've subclassed the Parse object, then you can use your subclass:

```
@NSManaged var myTag: Tag?
```